# SPAM - can admins do something please?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear admins, this is getting out of hand. 4 thousand spam messages in less than 24 hours. Pretty clear the "ROS answers" is not stopping spam, like it was supposed to.

Forgive me, but I never, ever, in more than 10 yeas of online groups, drowned like this in spam.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/179631/spam---can-admins-do-something-please-?/) by [ccapriotti](https://answers.ros.org/users/18779/ccapriotti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2014-06-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is addressed here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues/76

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ccapriotti](https://answers.ros.org/users/18779/ccapriotti/) on 2014-06-30**:
If you ask me, captcha, solved or not, working with moderation for new users, while nothing else is figured out. I volunteer for this sort of moderation, if the system allows for it.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-06-30**:
Please refer to the github issue for further discussion. As far as it seems what you are suggesting is the plan right now.